# Typo3 Fluid template cannot find css files using uri.resource

Tags: typo3, fluid

I followed [this tutorial](http://thomas.deuling.org/2011/06/create-a-complete-typo3-website-by-using-the-fluid-template-engine/) to create a Typo3 website using a Fluid template. However, I cannot get the CSS included in the template. In the  tag the following css is included:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
```

I rewrote this in the template to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{f:uri.resource(path:'css/bootstrap.css')}">
```

But the css is not included. The path to the template is:

```
fileadmin/templates/layouts/main.html
```

The path to the CSS file is:

```
fileadmin/templates/css/bootstrap.css
```

Where should I put the CSS files? And how should I include this css in the Fluid template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please keep in mind that pduerseler's way of doing it is better if you're using a plugin on many pages.

As for your problem, the uri.resource ViewHelper assumes that your resources are in the Resources/Public directory of your extension. So:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{f:uri.resource(path:'css/bootstrap.css')}">
```

points to

```
typo3conf/ext/yourExt/Resources/Public/css/bootstrap.css
```

It is not possible to point to a file in fileadmin with the resource ViewHelper, see https://git.typo3.org/Packages/TYPO3.CMS.git/blob/HEAD:/typo3/sysext/fluid/Classes/ViewHelpers/Uri/ResourceViewHelper.php.

Current best practise for a TYPO3 page template is to have the template of a TYPO3 Website in an own extension, see e.g. https://github.com/georgringer/modernpackage

Comment: But what if my template is in fileadmin/templates and there isn't any extension? This is the main site template, not an extension template. Where is uri.resource looking for my css?

Answer (score 3):

As a rule of thumb, you put JS and CSS files into your typoscript.

Example:

```
page = PAGE
page {
  includeCSS {
    myfile = path/to/my/file.css
  }

  includeJS {
    myfile = path/to/my/file.js
  }
}
```

This brings some benefits; You can organize your js and css in multiple files, and have TYPO3 concatenate and compress them by setting

```
config {
  concatenateJs = 1
  concatenateCss = 1

  compressJs = 1
  compressCss = 1
}
```

See more here: http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Page/Index.html